# Does retagging count as an edit?

Tags: support, editing, badges, retagging

When you retag a question, it displays on the question as an edit. However, does it actually count as an edit (such as toward the [Strunk & White](https://superuser.com/badges/12/strunk-white) or [Copy Editor](https://superuser.com/badges/57/copy-editor) badges)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.

Edits that are tallied toward the related editing badges [must satisfy the following:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445)

> - The post can not be your own, however community-wiki posts are eligible.
> - You must edit the title and/or body (i.e. editing the tags alone does not qualify)
> - Tag wiki posts are also eligible.
>
> So, to count for S&W/Copy Editor, the edit must cover the title, the body or both.